# Parcelable with optionally populated values

Tags: java, android, json, parcelable

I am getting information from Google Place Search API. I can decode the JSON Object just fine on my first Activity. I would like to take the user to a details page so I am trying to pass the information via a Parcelable. When an attribute isn't provided by Google (maybe they don't have ratings or something) I was able to get around it in the writeToParcel function by doing a null check on the class's attributes. However, it messes up the ordering of my decoding in the Constructor so that the wrong values get assigned to each subsequent attribute.

1) How should I handle when an attribute isn't provided?

2) Is there a more abstract way to decode / encode using reflections?

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Place> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Place>() {
    public Place createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Place(in);
    }

    public Place[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Place[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    if(capacity != null) {
        out.writeInt(capacity);
    }
    if(icon != null) {
        out.writeString(icon);
    }
    if(latitude != null) {
        out.writeDouble(latitude);  
    }
    if(longitude != null) {
        out.writeDouble(longitude); 
    }
    if(name != null) {
        out.writeString(name);
    }
    if(priceLevel != null) {
        out.writeInt(priceLevel);
    }
    if(rating != null) {
        out.writeDouble(rating);
    }
    if(vicinity != null) {
        out.writeString(vicinity);
    }
}

private Place(Parcel in) {
    this.capacity = in.readInt();
    this.icon = in.readString();
    this.latitude = in.readDouble();
    this.longitude = in.readDouble();
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.priceLevel = in.readInt();
    this.rating = in.readDouble();
    this.vicinity = in.readString();
}
```

Comment: Use Gson library to parse the JSON and "inject" it to the Place model. It handles null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding this really impressive site which properly formatted my class as a Parcelable. It handled null cleanly by using bytes.

http://www.parcelabler.com/

```
protected Place(Parcel in) {
    placeId = in.readString();
    latitude = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readDouble();
    longitude = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readDouble();
    icon = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    priceLevel = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readInt();
    rating = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readDouble();
    vicinity = in.readString();
    capacity = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : in.readInt();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(placeId);
    if (latitude == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeDouble(latitude);
    }
    if (longitude == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeDouble(longitude);
    }
    dest.writeString(icon);
    dest.writeString(name);
    if (priceLevel == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeInt(priceLevel);
    }
    if (rating == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeDouble(rating);
    }
    dest.writeString(vicinity);
    if (capacity == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeInt(capacity);
    }
}
```

Comment: All you did was add a byte as a placeholder when a null existed and then place a byte before a valid entry to indicate a value exists. Handling it this is way not more proper than how you were doing it before, or better than my approach, which removed the need for extra bytes by simply initializing values, or the approach provided by @kcoppock which was just to write the null values and check for null when retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current set up of checking for null before writing each value it sounds like the ordering is wrong because not all values are being written to the parcel. As you observed, the parcel is read/written in order so omitting values in the write phase will change the order of results when read back. You should be able to fix this by simply supplying a value for each variable written to the parcel. If there are instance variables (they look like they are) initialize each variable rather than using null (e.g. use empty strings or 0's for ints). You should then be able to write/read the parcel fine. Just check for your empty values on the other side so you know what fields to display.

If the null checks are related to `JSON` not containing the same values, simply use the contains method to check the `JSON` value before setting that value to your variable rather than writing to the parcel.

Answer (score 0):

Those `writeX()` methods all support null values as parameters -- you should simply remove the null checks and things will be handled as you expect (if the value is null, it will be null when recreated from the Parcel).